# Is it good way to update data in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I am updating existing data in a database. Basically, I am retrieving all data from the table and one by one I am updating each column manually. Do you think it's a good way? Or please suggest me another short way to do the same. My method is looking so long I mean a lot of lines to update.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveMovie(HttpPostedFileBase file, MovieViewModel model)
{
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var viewModel = new MovieViewModel
            {
                ProHouses = _context.ProHouses.ToList()
            };

            return View("AddMovie", viewModel);
        }

        if (model.Movies.Id == 0)
        {
            if (file != null)
            {
                Guid RandomName = Guid.NewGuid();
                var fileExtention = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
                var FileName = RandomName + fileExtention;
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/MovieTitle"), RandomName + fileExtention);
                file.SaveAs(path);
                model.Movies.TitleURL = FileName;
            }

            _context.Movies.Add(model.Movies);
        }
        else
        {
            var movieInTable = _context.Movies.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Id == model.Movies.Id);
            movieInTable.Budget = model.Movies.Budget;
            movieInTable.Writer = model.Movies.Writer;
            movieInTable.Country = model.Movies.Country;
            movieInTable.Genre = model.Movies.Genre;
            movieInTable.Duration = model.Movies.Duration;
            movieInTable.Plot = model.Movies.Plot;
            movieInTable.Name = model.Movies.Name;
            movieInTable.ProHouseId = model.Movies.ProHouseId;
            movieInTable.Rating = model.Movies.Rating;
            movieInTable.Director = model.Movies.Director;
            movieInTable.Year = model.Movies.Year;
            movieInTable.TitleURL = model.Movies.TitleURL;
        }

        _context.SaveChanges();

        ViewBag.Message = "Movie Added";

        return View("Confirmation");
}
```

I am confused about this part:

```
else
{
    var movieInTable = _context.Movies.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Id == model.Movies.Id);
    movieInTable.Budget = model.Movies.Budget;
    movieInTable.Writer = model.Movies.Writer;
    movieInTable.Country = model.Movies.Country;
    movieInTable.Genre = model.Movies.Genre;
    movieInTable.Duration = model.Movies.Duration;
    movieInTable.Plot = model.Movies.Plot;
    movieInTable.Name = model.Movies.Name;
    movieInTable.ProHouseId = model.Movies.ProHouseId;
    movieInTable.Rating = model.Movies.Rating;
    movieInTable.Director = model.Movies.Director;
    movieInTable.Year = model.Movies.Year;
    movieInTable.TitleURL = model.Movies.TitleURL;
}
```

Comment: There are a lot of different ways to accomplish that. You can use a copy constructor, an interface based coercion, an attribute mapper, or a service method.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the written code is hard to reuse and you will have difficulties during the maintenance. Suppose a situation that you are repeating such code and use it in several files, suddenly you discover that another field is required and needs to be added. So you have to alter all the codes.

Second, it is recommended to not put your **Data Manipulation** codes in controller. Try to create another layer (class project) in order to put such codes. Using Automapper class library with absolutely help you reducing mappings.

Otherwise, as Travis suggested above, you can use a constructor in order to fill the properties.